# Chage ListModel data in qml file using C++

Tags: c++, qml, listmodel

There is an example : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-qmlscatter-example.html  of using qml and QtQuick to create a 3D scatter.

How can I chage (delete, append, clear) ListModel data in Data.qml file using C++ code?

Data.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Item {
     property alias model: dataModel
     property alias modelTwo: dataModelTwo
     property alias modelThree: dataModelThree

     ListModel {
         id: dataModel
         ListElement{ xPos: -10.0; yPos: 5.0; zPos: -5.0 }
         ListElement{ xPos: -9.0; yPos: 3.0; zPos: -4.5 }
         ListElement{ xPos: -8.5; yPos: 4.1; zPos: -4.0 }
         ...
     }
     ...
}
```

Comment: See this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html Take a special look on the section: **warning**. Then you might want to create a model in C++, and expose it as ContextProperty to QML and use it there. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the model from C++, you can register an object that implements `QAbstractItemModel` to the QML runtime.

`QAbstraactItemModel` is a fairly complex class, there are helpful derived types that may make implementation easier, but that depends on your use case. For instance, `QAbstractListModel` is useful for lists, as opposed to tables, and `QStandardItemModel` is useful for data that can be easily modeled at `QStandardItems`.

Once you've implemented the model in C++ you need to make it available to the QML runtime. This is done using `setContextProperty` on `QQmlContext`. Generally the `QQmlContext` you want is the `rootContext()` of your `QQmlEngine`.

The registration might look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    MyListModel *model = new MyListModel;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myListModel", model);
    engine.load(":/myqmlapp.qml");
    app.exec();
    [...]
}
```

To access the model from within QML you use the name that it was registered with, in this case `myListModel`:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item {
    ListView {
        model: myListModel
    }
}
```